# /bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' while using dir() function in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I am getting tis error with quoted string path
I have path variable like PATH_VAR and I want output C:/test/tools so below is recipe

```
PATH_VAR = "C:/test/tools/compiler_name.exe"
.PHONY : TEST
TEST: 
    echo $(dir $(PATH_VAR))
```

but I am getting error as follows

```
echo "C:/test/tools/
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [TEST] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`$(dir $(arg))`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) call
extracts the value of `arg` up to and including the last `/`. So the value of
`$(dir $(PATH_VAR))` = `$(dir "C:/test/tools/compiler_name.exe")` is:

```
"C:/test/tools/
```

which is an unterminated quoted string. Remove the quotes from around `"C:/test/tools/compiler_name.exe"`

Comment: Thanks Mike I understand this, Please let me know how i can get 

    "C:/test/build_tool"

Comment: @Vicky  One question at a time on Stackoverflow. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
and if you have another problem you cannot solve by yourself, ask a new question.